# Moving SQL Server to another computer

Tags: sql-server

I am in the process of running a lot of data on a computer that has more power than the one I am currently using. However the data is in a SQL Server instance that I have already created and do not want to change. Is there a way to set up the same SQL Server on the other computer?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to migrate the one or more databases from a SQL Server instance on one computer to a SQL Server instance running on another computer?

Comment: if possible, i want to retain the same server but have it on a different computer if possible. and if not possible how can i access/manipulate the data from a different server?

Comment: yes, essentially i have a program running that is collecting data and storing it into a sql database, but the computer it is running on is to slow and i want to use a better computer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the following assumes that you are a SQL Server administrator on both of the instances...

Generally, you can follow these steps:

1. On the source computer, note the location of your database's files
2. On the source computer, detach the database from the source computer's SQL Server instance
3. Move the database files to the proper directories on the target computer
4. On the target computer's SQL Server instance, attach the database
5. Repeat for each of the databases you wish to migrate

Comment: Backup/restore is much, much, much safer than detach/attach. Primarily because, if something goes wrong while the file is detached, you now have ZERO copies of your database.

Answer (score 2):

Or just make a backup copies of all databases on source computer, then restore them to the SQL Server instance on the target computer.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the above approaches (detach-copy-attach, or backup-restore) will require some additional fiddling in the following two areas:

- Scheduled tasks
- User logins

However, SSIS is worth a look.  Three of the tasks in [SQL Server Integration Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139892.aspx) will be of interest to you:Transfer Logins, Transfer Database, Transfer Jobs.  If you don't have access to SSIS, you can script these stages.  See the [SSMS documentation for Scripting Jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191450%28v=sql.105%29.aspx); and there are various options for transferring logins too - such as [this MS Support document](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992).  You can even go really old school and use BCP to export syslogins, import that into a temporary table on your new server, and go through adding the appropriate users and then fixing the orphaned users in your databases.

Comment: There are some other things that could be added to the list - ensuring the instance name is the same, ensuring the server collation is the same, all sp_configure options match, service account, permissions, etc.